# Angular 6 - Lazy loading auxilary issue

Tags: angular, angular6, router-outlet

I need load detail in lazy module based on url. So, I had used lazy auxilary routing. But, when I use auxilary routing, i'm facing below issue.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'lazy/aux1' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'lazy/aux1' at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@angular/router@6.1.7/bundles/router.umd.js:1455:20)
>   at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector]
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@angular/router@6.1.7/bundles/router.umd.js:1436:33)
>   at CatchSubscriber.error
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/rxjs@6.3.2/internal/operators/catchError.js:48:31)
>   at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/rxjs@6.3.2/internal/Subscriber.js:96:26)
>   at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/rxjs@6.3.2/internal/Subscriber.js:74:18)
>   at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/rxjs@6.3.2/internal/Subscriber.js:96:26)
>   at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/rxjs@6.3.2/internal/Subscriber.js:74:18)
>   at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/rxjs@6.3.2/internal/Subscriber.js:96:26)
>   at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/rxjs@6.3.2/internal/Subscriber.js:74:18)
>   at TapSubscriber._error
>   (https://lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/rxjs@6.3.2/internal/operators/tap.js:75:26)

Please find the sample link and reproducing steps below:

1. Go to sample link https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j
2. Click lazy-route link 
   [image]
3. Then click any one of aux route
   [image]

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? This is a known [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-301787482) and appears to have not been solved until Angular v6.1.x.

Comment: @Narm: I'm using angular 6.1.7. I had created a sample with latest version only.

Comment: Have a look at the answer from @kentoj, in the link to the issue in my first comment. It appears there are solutions to your issue. At the very least, looking at your code in your StackBlitz you're not properly routing using 'routerLink` for named router-outlets to begin with.

Comment: If I followed that way, url looks like /b/(c//myoutlet:something). But I need to show the url like /b/c only. So, that solution not help to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes,You don't need to name your outlet and mentioning outlet name in routing

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LazyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'aux1', component: Aux1Component
      },
      {
        path: 'aux2', component: Aux2Component
      },
      {
        path: 'aux3', component: Aux3Component
      }
    ]
  }
];

<a [routerLink]="['/']">
    back
</a>
&nbsp;
<a routerLink="aux1">
    aux1 route
</a>
&nbsp;

<a [routerLink]="['aux2']">
    aux2 route
</a>
&nbsp;

<a [routerLink]="['aux3']">
    aux3 route
</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then you can either use `<a routerLink="aux1">` or `<a [routerLink]="['aux1']">`

see update [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-5x4jxw)

Answer (score 0):

from your example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-load-auxilary-b7vpg-e2ax7j), you just need a couple of things:

I've been reading a lot these days about routing and what came back often is you can not have lazy route with empty path, so add in lazy.module routes config:

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'lazy', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

then modifies your empty lazy path name to 'lazy'

```
 path: 'lazy',
```

Then as comments suggested, named outlet have a specific way to use : (first router link directive should be)

```
[routerLink]="[ { outlets: { aux :['aux1'] }} ]"
```

with that your stackblitz is now working